# iphone NSLog when displaying an array

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nslog

First when I am using nslog to log the contents of an array, why is it that some of the objects in the array (all strings) have quotation marks around them and some dont?

The log will look like:

```
"Item 1",
"item 2",
item3,
"item4"
```

This leads to my second part of the question...

The array in question is being used as a dataSource for a tableView, and only the only object that is showing up in the table view is the one without quotation marks.

Comment: post some code where you populate the array..

Answer (score 2):

Item3 doesn't contain a space and therefore doesn't require quotes.